# java + threaded discussion forum + iphone app

Tags: java, iphone, forum

What are some of the free discussion forums available which I can integrate to my java based application running on tomcat? I did look at jforum and http://java-source.net/open-source/forum-software, but I couldnt make out which ones are good/bad, or which ones are still being developed actively.

I also want to write an iphone App that talks to the forum. Are there are any free forum softwares that suit these requirements?

Thanks.